# The reals as continuous image of the irrationals

Tags: gn.general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

In the Wikipedia article about [descriptive set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descriptive_set_theory) I read that $\mathbb{R}$ (with its usual topology) is a Polish space, and that every Polish space

1) can be obtained as a continuous image of the Baire space $\mathcal{N}$

2) can be obtained as the image of a continuous bijection defined on a closed subset of the Baire space.

Then I learn from the Wikipedia article on [Baire space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_space_(set_theory)) that it is actually homeomorphic to the irrational numbers with their usual subspace topology inherited from the real line.

So my questions:

> Can we describe explicitly a surjective continuous map from the irrationals to $\mathbb{R}$?
>
> Same for a continuous bijection from a closed subset of the irrationals to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: (Perhaps I should have posted this on MathSE instead of MO?)

Comment: For future visitors, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4498159/does-there-exist-a-bijective-continuous-map-from-the-irrationals-onto-the-reals for some continuous **bijections** from the irrationals to the real line.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For any irrational number $x$, let $f(x)$ be the real number arising from the integer part of $x$, together with every other digit of the rest of the expansion of $x$.

This is surjective, since one may interleave the digits of any real $y$ with any nonrepeating pattern, and thereby find an irrational $x$ with $f(x)=y$.  This is continuous, since if $x_n\to x$, then $f(x_n)\to f(x)$.

Comment: Surely I'm being dense, but what do you mean by "taking every other digit of the expansion of $x$"? 

Comment: I mean, for example, that $3.1415926535897932384\ldots$ maps to $3.1196387334\ldots$

Comment: Ok, so you meant: the integer part is the same while the $n$-th digit of the fractionary expansion is replaced by the $(2n-1)$-th digit.

Comment: (or: the $n$-th digit is replaced by the $\sigma(n)$-th, where $\sigma$ is any monotone function)

Comment: Yes, that's right. But note the slight complication that the resulting expansion may be something like $0.999999\ldots$, which means it is really $1$. 

Comment: I think I will choose this answer, even though also the one by R.Israel was elegant, because the former only relies on the first properties of real numbers and doesn't use the existence of space-filling curves.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I think that "slight complication" is a larger problem than you make it seem. $0.22$ maps to $0.2$, but the sequence $(0.219,0.21999,0.2199999,\dots)$ maps to $(0.29,0.299,0.2999,\dots)$. $x_n\to x$ but $f(x_n)\not\to f(x)$.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger But $f$ is only defined on the irrational numbers, and your numbers are all rational.

Comment: Oh, good point. Objection withdrawn.

Answer (score 27):

Let $C$ be a space-filling curve, i.e. a continuous function from $\mathbb R$ onto ${\mathbb R}^2$. Then the first component $C(t)_1$ is a continuous function from $\mathbb R$ onto $\mathbb R$ that hits each real number uncountably many times.  Since there are only countably many rationals, the restriction to the irrationals is also surjective.

Comment: Thank you for the very clear answer to my first question. What about the second question on continuous bijection from a closed set of irrationals?

Answer (score 7):

Here's another simple explicit function that maps the irrationals onto the real numbers. It is defined on the whole real line.

Consider the continuous piece-wise linear function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, with slope $f'(x)=-1$ or $f'(x)=+1$ according whether $\lfloor x/\sqrt 2\rfloor=0\, \mathrm{ mod} 3 $, or not (like [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6f/3-4_rhythm_metre_meter_time_measure.ogg)). So $f(x)=x/3+O(1)$ as $|x|\to\infty$ and it is therefore surjective; precisely, any of its fiber has three points, and the arithmetic mean of some two of these is an odd multiple of $\sqrt{2}$. This means that  the equation $f(x)=c$ has always an irrational solution, whatever is $c\in\mathbb{R}$.

**rmk.** Note that replacing $\sqrt 2$ with $\pi$ produces a map that maps the transcendental numbers onto $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 6):

A surjection from $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is given by
$$f \mapsto f(0) - f(1) + \sum_{k = 2}^\infty \frac{\min(f(2k),1)-\min(f(2k+1),1)}{2^{2k-4}}$$
A homeomorphism from the irrational numbers (with the Euclidean topology) to $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ is given by the continued-fraction expansion.

The displayed map is onto, constructively. For the continued-fraction expansion map to be constructive, we need to define irrational numbers as those reals $x \in \mathbb{R}$ for which $|x - q| > 0$ for all $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ (as opposed to those reals which are not rational).

Comment: The only way I can make heads or tails of this formula is that $f$ is not an irrational number as requested by the OP, but an element of the Baire space, $f\colon\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Emil Ah! It now makes sense.

Comment: Oops, I added a comment to that effect.

Answer (score 4):

For the second question, remember that the subset only has to be closed *in the irrationals*, not as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. With that in mind, you can take the closed subset to be the irrationals in $(-1,1)$ union some countable discrete set of irrationals. On $(-1,0)$, define $f$ by $x\mapsto \frac{1}{x}+1$; on $(0,1)$, by $x\mapsto \frac{1}{x}-1$, and on the discrete set, choose some bijection with $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 2):

Count the rational numbers as $(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots)$.  Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be defined at the nonpositive integers by $f(n)=(-1)^nn$, and on the positive integer multiples of $\sqrt 2$ by $f(n\sqrt 2)=a_n$.  Let $f$ be piecewise linear between the points just defined.  Then the restriction of $f$ to $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$ is a continuous surjection from the irrationals to $\mathbb R$.