# Is there a continuous surjection $\omega^\omega\to \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: gn.general-topology

Let $\omega$ be endowed with the discrete topology, and let $\mathbb{R}$ carry the Euclidean topology. Is there a continuous surjective map $f:\omega^\omega\to \mathbb{R}$?

(I suppose this would entail that there is a contiuous surjective map $f:\omega^\omega \to \mathbb{R}^\omega.$)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1225140/every-perfect-polish-space-is-a-continuous-1-1-image-of-the-baire-space#comment2513462_1225140

Comment: Just to be clear: if you follow Asaf's link, you'll see that the answer to your question is yes, and that even more is true. You can obtain $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb R^\omega$ as the continuous *bijective* image of $\omega^\omega$. In other words, these topologies can be realized as strictly coarser topologies on $\omega^\omega$. (I'm not sure this question will remain open, but personally I don't think it's a bad question -- it's an interesting fact and, though well-known, not trivial to prove if you haven't seen it before.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is no longer relevant (answered in the linked question).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes - consider the map sending a sequence of naturals to the corresponding continued fraction representation. (OK fine this hits $[0,\infty)$, but that's easy to fix.)

More is true: any [Polish space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_space) is the continuous image of $\omega^\omega$. The converse fails, though, even for uncountable Polish spaces - there is no continuous surjection from $2^\omega$ to $\omega^\omega$, since only the former is compact.

Cantor space ($2^\omega$) *is* universal in an appropriate sense, though - every compact metric space is a continuous image of Cantor space.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks @NoahSchweber also for the further comments!!

Comment: Well. Also $\Bbb R$ is connected, so any continuous function to the Baire space is constant.

Comment: The other one that's often useful is that there is a continuous embedding from any separable metrizable space $X$ to the Hilbert cube $[0,1]^\omega$.  (Pick a countable dense subset $\{x_n\} \subset X$ and a metric $d$, and consider the map $x \mapsto (d(x_1, x), d(x_2,x), \dots)$.)

Comment: Slight quibble: continued fractions only get you irrational numbers (the map in question is a homeomorphism). There are various simple tricks to get you the rest, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/112127/the-reals-as-continuous-image-of-the-irrationals

Comment: I'm familiar with continued fractions which terminate, but not with ones containing zeroes. I can see how to interpret the latter when the sequences are eventually-nonzero, but find it non-obvious that ones built from eventually-zero sequences even make sense. (Edit: I'd be grateful for a reference on this, and didn't mean to ask for a direct explanation. Searching for "continued fractions" "containing zeroes" and the like hasn't turned up anything useful so far.)

Comment: Ok, I think I see now. Of course, n + 1/(0 + 1/x) = n + x, which takes care of sequences which are *not* eventually-zero, but might not be eventually-nonzero either. Then for a sequence of all zeroes, solving x = 0 + 1/x gives x = 1. I found this unfamiliar because I'm used to thinking of a partial fraction as just the limit of its convergents.

Comment: @RobinSaunders Haha, overlapping comments. I think the state of affairs is: it can make sense, and did to me back when I wrote this post, but current-me was hopelessly confused.

Comment: Good to know I wasn't missing something incredibly obvious!

Comment: Final(?) twist: x = 1/x actually has two solutions! At least -1 is also an integer, so in some sense you can get each rational "one way or the other".

Comment: @RobinSaunders Isn't it enough to just look at the sequence $$a_1+1, a_1+{1\over a_2+1}, a_1+{1\over a_2+{1\over a_3+1}}, ...$$ to handle things? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Sure, you could take that as a definition which agrees with the usual one (in terms of strictly positive sequences) where the latter exists.

Comment: Note, though, that if $a_n$ were all $\ge 1$ then you could choose any $k$ you liked and $[a_0; a_1, ..., a_n + k]$ would always converge to the true value (I'm used to choosing $k = 0$). But if $a_n$ are all $= 0$ then the "convergents" oscillate between $k$ and $1/k$, and only converge if you happened to choose $k = 1$. This is surely evidence that $1$ is "the right answer", especially when combined with the observation about solutions to $x = 0 + 1/x$, but it doesn't feel watertight.

Comment: Put another way: the corresponding function from $\omega^\omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is discontinuous at every eventually-zero sequence, and these form a dense set.