# Order-preserving surjection ${\mathbb N}^{\mathbb N}\to [0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, order-theory, posets, lattice-theory

This is kind of a continuation of a recent [(closed) question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/280964/is-there-a-continuous-surjection-omega-omega-to-mathbbr).

Is there an order-preserving surjective function $f:{\mathbb N}^{\mathbb N}\to [0,\infty)$ (where for $a,b\in {\mathbb N}^{\mathbb N}$ we have $a\leq b$ if $a(n) \le b(n)$ for all $n\in {\mathbb N}$)?

Thanks to [Jeremy Rickard](https://mathoverflow.net/users/22989/jeremy-rickard) who made me aware that a previous version of this question was trivial and therefore uninteresting.

Comment: Just an objection to notation.  I think that $\omega$ is an ordinal, and $\omega^\omega$ makes sense in the arithmetic of ordinals.  For your set I would write $\mathbb N^\mathbb N$, and then no (sensible) person would think I mean ordinal exponentiation.

Comment: Right, thanks @GeraldEdgar - will change

Comment: @GeraldEdgar I believe that $\omega^\omega$ is relatively common notation for [the Baire space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_space_(set_theory)). (But I am by no means an expert on descriptive set theory.) Although to be honest, I am a bit confused how this is related to the linked post - which talks about the Baire space. AFAICT only the ordering (not the topology) on the set $\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$ plays role in *this post*.

Comment: Even if it is common (among set theorists), it is still confusing. Just as confusing as writing $5^2$ for the set of maps from a two-element set to a five-element set.

Comment: @Gerald: That last claim seems dubious. This is more like the case of $2^2$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. Let us isomorphically identify the poset of functions $\omega \to \omega$ (under the pointwise order) with the set of functions $\omega \to \mathbb{N}_2 = \{n \in \mathbb{N}: n \geq 2\}$, again ordered pointwise.

Now in fact there is an *isomorphism* of posets $\mathbb{N}_2^\omega \to [1, \infty)$ given by continued fractions

$$(a_1, a_2, \ldots) \mapsto a_1 - \frac1{a_2 - \frac1{a_3 - \ldots}}$$

provided we endow the domain with *dictionary* order. Then finish by observing that the identity function

$$(\mathbb{N}_2^\omega)_{\text{pointwise}} \to (\mathbb{N}_2^\omega)_{\text{dict}}$$

is order-preserving.

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively, you may map a sequence of positive integers $(a_1,a_2,\dots)$ to $1-2^{-a_1}-2^{-a_1-a_2}-\dots$. This is order-preserving surjection onto $[0,1)$. Apply a function like $\tan (\frac{\pi}2x)$ to get a surjection onto $[0,+\infty)$.